# Shortcut Key to Open file with non- default programs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Suppose there are two programs installed in my PC to open a PDF file. (Adobe Reader and Foxit)

Foxit is set as the default program to open pdf files. Now I want to open pdf files with Adobe Reader but I don't want to use(click on) "Open With" from context menu. Is there any way that I can open a file with a different application I want?

For Example, an ideal way to open in Adobe Reader would be:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>(or any key)+<kbd>Double click</kbd> on the file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To open a dropdown along with the Open With.. menu for a selected file, the keyboard shortcut is:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Look at the dropdown that opens and find out the position of Adobe Acrobat in the list. in my case, it is the first option, so I can just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If it is below that, press the down arrow key for  the required number of times and Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If your file is not in the list, then the shortcut to open with other apps is:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for sharing the shortcut info. In order to use this, I still need to roam around the keyboard which does not fulfill the purpose of shortcut. Any other way to use single key strock (any 3rd party software or reg modification if needed) ?

Comment: I don't think Windows allows you to open files with certain apps using shortcuts. The default shortcut I've shown must be memorized if you want to be effective. You can, however, open certain apps with Keyboard shortcuts. https://lifehacker.com/5783366/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-launch-anything-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how to open a certain file with a specific program:

```
%windir%\System32\notepad.exe C:\Users\you\test.txt
```

This will open the file "`test.txt`" in the regular notepad, regardless of which text editor you have as the default.
The same principal can be used to any file. Just create the shortcut first, then open its Properties, and in the Shortcut tab, edit the "Target" field as described above. Good luck!